# SMTP Relay Sending a copy of every email and relay

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail, relay, postfix-mta

I have a an application which I do not have access to the code and I need to keep trace of every email it sends out.

Right now, the only way I can think of is creating a SMTP relay using either sendmail or postfix then sending a copy to another email address before continuing with the relay.

Is it posssible and do you have example of config file for doing this ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

In postfix main.cf you can use BCC functionality:

Ex:
`always_bcc = address@example.com`
        
- Deliver a copy of all mail to the specified address.

Comment: Thank you very much